# How to parse PE exported functions in C

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

I want to list all exported functions from an PE (PortableExecutable).

Here is some code:

```
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dos_header = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)PE_Header;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(PE_Header + dos_header->e_lfanew);

// How can I go on?
```

The following line gives me an AccessViolation because the `VirtualAddress` Member is to big:

```
printf("Export Table %s\n", PE_Header + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT].VirtualAddress);
```

I don’t know how to go on and list all exported functions.

Can you provide some sample working code?

Comment: Doesn't `ntHeader` already include `PEHeader + ...`? To me it looks as if you do it twice in `PEHeader + ntHeader->...`.

Comment: @Thomas: No.in winnt.h specifyed the member of IMAGE_DOS_HEADER: LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header

Comment: You should cast PE_Header to something byte-sized, like: `((char*)PE_Header) + ...`
And it's a 32bit executable you are reading, right?

Comment: @ssbssa yes its 32bit exe

Comment: When you're printing, you did print the entire `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY`, not the `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY->AddressOfFunctions`

Comment: @ThomasWeller After seeing the https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-in-C++ question, it's deferencing the `e_lfanew` in `dos_header`.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you finding the exports:

```
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(argv[1]);

PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)(DWORD)hModule;
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)hModule + dosHeader->e_lfanew);
DWORD dwEATStart = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[0].VirtualAddress;
PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY exportDirectory = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)((DWORD_PTR)hModule);

DWORD* addressOfFunctions = (DWORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfFunctions);
DWORD* addressOfNames = (DWORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNames);
WORD* addressOfNameOrdinals = (WORD*)((DWORD)hModule + exportDirectory->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
printf("\tordinal\t\thint\t\tRVA\t\tattribute\t\tname\n");
for (DWORD i = 0; i < exportDirectory->NumberOfFunctions; i++)
{
    DWORD functionRVA = addressOfFunctions[i];
    const char* functionName = NULL;

    for (DWORD j = 0; j < exportDirectory->NumberOfNames; j++)
    {
        if (addressOfNameOrdinals[j] == i)
        {
            printf("%s\n",((DWORD)hModule + addressOfNames[j]));
            break;
        }
    }

}

FreeLibrary(hModule);
```

Comment: Help in what way? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77338945/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: very bad code. absolute wrong how you process named functions. lost export by ordinal. not handle forward export